# Deserilizing Json Response of HttpClient using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I am calling a third-party API with HttpClient GET Request and it works fine. The response is quite complex of objects. All I want to do is to extract a specific attribute within these objects. Here is the response Json

```
  "creationTime": "2021-11-06T12:22:49.602Z",
  "currency": "USD",
  "customer": {
    "firstName": "xxxx"
  },
  "id": "xxxx",
  "lastUpdatedTime": "2021-11-06T12:22:51.689Z",
  "merchant": "xxx",
  "merchantAmount": 33,
  "merchantCategoryCode": "5311",
  "merchantCurrency": "USD",
  "reference": "XX",
  "result": "SUCCESS",
  "sourceOfFunds": {
    "provided": {
      "card": {
        "brand": "MASTERCARD",
        "expiry": {
          "month": "X",
          "year": "XX"
        },
        "fundingMethod": "DEBIT",
        "nameOnCard": "XXX",
        "number": "XXXXX123",
        "scheme": "MASTERCARD",
        "storedOnFile": "NOT_STORED"
      }
    },
    "type": "CARD"
  },
  "status": "CAPTURED",
  "totalAuthorizedAmount": 33,
  "totalCapturedAmount": 33,
  "totalRefundedAmount": 0,
  "transaction": [
    {
      "3DSecure": {
        "acsEci": "02",
        "authenticationToken": "XXXX+XXXX=",
        "paResStatus": "Y",
        "veResEnrolled": "Y",
        "xid": "mmmXXX"
      },
      "3DSecureId": "XXX",
      "authorizationResponse": {
        "cardSecurityCodeError": "M",
        "commercialCardIndicator": "1",
        "date": "1106",
        "financialNetworkCode": "XX",
        "financialNetworkDate": "2021-11-06",
        "posData": "XXX",
        "posEntryMode": "xxx",
        "processingCode": "000000",
        "responseCode": "00",
        "stan": "22443",
        "time": "122249",
        "transactionIdentifier": "014VPH"
      },
      "customer": {
        "firstName": "XXXX"
      },
      "device": {
     
      },
      "gatewayEntryPoint": "CHECKOUT",
      "merchant": "XXXX",
      "order": {
        "amount": 33,
        "chargeback": {
          "amount": 0,
          "currency": "USD"
        },
        "creationTime": "2021-11-06T12:22:49.602Z",
        "currency": "USD",
        "description": "243",
        "id": "xxxxx",
        "lastUpdatedTime": "2021-11-06T12:22:51.689Z",
        "merchantAmount": 33,
        "merchantCategoryCode": "xxx",
        "merchantCurrency": "IQD",
        "reference": "243",
        "status": "CAPTURED",
        "totalAuthorizedAmount": 33,
        "totalCapturedAmount": 33,
        "totalRefundedAmount": 0
      },
      "response": {
        "acquirerCode": "00",
        "acquirerMessage": "Approved",
        "cardSecurityCode": {
          "acquirerCode": "M",
          "gatewayCode": "MATCH"
        },
        "gatewayCode": "APPROVED"
      },
      "result": "SUCCESS",
      "sourceOfFunds": {
        "provided": {
          "card": {
            "brand": "MASTERCARD",
            "expiry": {
              "month": "x",
              "year": "xx"
            },
            "fundingMethod": "DEBIT",
            "nameOnCard": "xxxxx",
            "number": "xxxxxx",
            "scheme": "MASTERCARD",
            "storedOnFile": "NOT_STORED"
          }
        },
        "type": "CARD"
      },
      "timeOfLastUpdate": "2021-11-06T12:22:51.689Z",
      "timeOfRecord": "2021-11-06T12:22:49.617Z",
 
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to extract **"status": "CAPTURED"** and   **"acquirerCode": "00"** . here is what I tried

```
  var client = new HttpClient();
            string _ContentType = "application/json";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(_ContentType));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64EncodedAuthenticationString);

            var _UserAgent = "d-fens HttpClient";
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", _UserAgent);
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            response = await client.GetAsync(api_URL);
  
            var resContent =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
 
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 
            return Ok(resContent);
```

Extracting these values would solve the issue I'm facing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your json is not valid , pls fix it. And  also what  problem do you have?  Can you get the json file from http client request?  Or you just  can not deserialize json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you need just this 2 values the easiest way is

```
var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

var result = JObject.Parse(json);
var status= result["status"];
var acquirerCode= result["transaction"][0]["response"]["acquirerCode"];
```

output

```
CAPTURED
00
```

And there is a hard way

```
var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

 var jsonDeserialized=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

 var status= jsonDeserialized.Status;
     
var acquirerCode=jsonDeserialized.Transaction.Select(t =>  t.Response.AcquirerCode).FirstOrDefault();
```

classes

```
public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("creationTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset CreationTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("customer")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastUpdatedTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchant")]
        public string Merchant { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchantAmount")]
        public long MerchantAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchantCategoryCode")]
        public long MerchantCategoryCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchantCurrency")]
        public string MerchantCurrency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("reference")]
        public string Reference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public string Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sourceOfFunds")]
        public SourceOfFunds SourceOfFunds { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalAuthorizedAmount")]
        public long TotalAuthorizedAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalCapturedAmount")]
        public long TotalCapturedAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalRefundedAmount")]
        public long TotalRefundedAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("transaction")]
        public Transaction[] Transaction { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Customer
    {
        [JsonProperty("firstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SourceOfFunds
    {
        [JsonProperty("provided")]
        public Provided Provided { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Provided
    {
        [JsonProperty("card")]
        public Card Card { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Card
    {
        [JsonProperty("brand")]
        public string Brand { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expiry")]
        public Expiry Expiry { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fundingMethod")]
        public string FundingMethod { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nameOnCard")]
        public string NameOnCard { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("scheme")]
        public string Scheme { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("storedOnFile")]
        public string StoredOnFile { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Expiry
    {
        [JsonProperty("month")]
        public string Month { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("year")]
        public string Year { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Transaction
    {
        [JsonProperty("3DSecure")]
        public The3DSecure The3DSecure { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("3DSecureId")]
        public string The3DSecureId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("authorizationResponse")]
        public AuthorizationResponse AuthorizationResponse { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("customer")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("device")]
        public Device Device { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gatewayEntryPoint")]
        public string GatewayEntryPoint { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchant")]
        public string Merchant { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("order")]
        public Order Order { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("response")]
        public Response Response { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public string Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("sourceOfFunds")]
        public SourceOfFunds SourceOfFunds { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timeOfLastUpdate")]
        public DateTimeOffset TimeOfLastUpdate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timeOfRecord")]
        public DateTimeOffset TimeOfRecord { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AuthorizationResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("cardSecurityCodeError")]
        public string CardSecurityCodeError { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("commercialCardIndicator")]
        public long CommercialCardIndicator { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public long Date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("financialNetworkCode")]
        public string FinancialNetworkCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("financialNetworkDate")]
        public DateTimeOffset FinancialNetworkDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("posData")]
        public string PosData { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("posEntryMode")]
        public string PosEntryMode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("processingCode")]
        public string ProcessingCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("responseCode")]
        public string ResponseCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("stan")]
        public long Stan { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("time")]
        public long Time { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("transactionIdentifier")]
        public string TransactionIdentifier { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Device
    {
    }

    public partial class Order
    {
        [JsonProperty("amount")]
        public long Amount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("chargeback")]
        public Chargeback Chargeback { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("creationTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset CreationTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
    
        public long Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastUpdatedTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchantAmount")]
        public long MerchantAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchantCategoryCode")]
        public string MerchantCategoryCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchantCurrency")]
        public string MerchantCurrency { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("reference")]
        public long Reference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalAuthorizedAmount")]
        public long TotalAuthorizedAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalCapturedAmount")]
        public long TotalCapturedAmount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalRefundedAmount")]
        public long TotalRefundedAmount { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Chargeback
    {
        [JsonProperty("amount")]
        public long Amount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currency")]
        public string Currency { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Response
    {
        [JsonProperty("acquirerCode")]
        public string AcquirerCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("acquirerMessage")]
        public string AcquirerMessage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("cardSecurityCode")]
        public CardSecurityCode CardSecurityCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gatewayCode")]
        public string GatewayCode { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class CardSecurityCode
    {
        [JsonProperty("acquirerCode")]
        public string AcquirerCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("gatewayCode")]
        public string GatewayCode { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class The3DSecure
    {
        [JsonProperty("acsEci")]
        public string AcsEci { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("authenticationToken")]
        public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("paResStatus")]
        public string PaResStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("veResEnrolled")]
        public string VeResEnrolled { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("xid")]
        public string Xid { get; set; }
    }
```